# Flow : Formula for record name on update

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, formula-field, flow-builder

I'm pretty (very) new with Salesforce Flows.

I'm trying to rename child records, after the parent has been created.

It basically replicates what is in this video, but with different objects
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F9cM23qfWr4

My issue is with the naming of my child records :
My objective is to name the records with "*Parent Record Name*" & " " & "*some other value stored on a field of the child object*"

So my assignment is as below, and names the record
[image]

Detail of the formula :
"OtherFieldFromChildRecord" would be where i would like to reference a value stored on the child record.
[image]

I can manage to get the {!$Record.Name}, but how can i manager the other field value?

Many thanks,
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you can use Resource type as a formula

and formula will be like that

[image]

So from that loop variable, it will always take the latest one, and you can select any field from that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much !

Works fine,
BUT i had to make a small adjustment, i did read about it in another post :

Directly referencing in my formula ({!Loop.Name}, in your screenshot) wasn't sufficient,
I had to create a fist formula, to get the second part i wanted to have in my record name (the "OtherFieldFromChildRecord" of my initial post)
[image]

And after that, built a formula like in your screenshot, using the above fomula :

[image]

Many thanks